# Can't update mysql database with text

Tags: php, mysql

I can update my database using the following code:

```
$id = 1;
$client = 3456;
$sql = "UPDATE production SET client=$client WHERE id=$id";
```

However, if the `$client` variable is a text string (instead of numeric), it won't work.

```
$id = 1;
$client = "some text";
$sql = "UPDATE production SET client=$client WHERE id=$id";
```

The client field in my database is VARCHAR with a limit of 50 characters. Is there anything obvious I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add single or double quotes at start and end of string to make is string in `mysql` query.

Replace

```
$sql = "UPDATE production SET client=$client WHERE id=$id";
```

With

```
$sql = "UPDATE production SET client='$client' WHERE id=$id";
```

The above can break if there is single quote in string so you can use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to value.

Try

```
$sql = "UPDATE production SET client='".addslashes($client)."' WHERE id=$id";
```

**Note**:

There are SQL injection possibilities in above query. Please try to use `prepare query` to prevent SQL injections

Comment: I knew it would be something obvious that a fresh set of eyes would see straight away. Thanks so much!

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE production SET client='$client' WHERE id=$id"; with $sql = "UPDATE production SET client='$client' WHERE id='$id'";

Comment: If $client could contains some `'` character, you could use : `$sql = 'UPDATE production SET client='. addslashes($client) .' WHERE id=$id';`

Comment: @user1267980 I am glad it works for you. Please mark tick on my answer if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

add single quotes in query while you pass the string like this,

```
$sql = "UPDATE production SET client='$client' WHERE id=$id";
```